# How can I calculate the memory and CPU resources used by an application submitted through a SPARK job in HDInsight

Tags: memory, cpu-usage, azure-hdinsight

My client is using **HDInsight** as their Big Data platform and as part of on-going system administration needs to record **total memory** and **CPU** consumption of various applications run through **Spark**. As the HDInsight product configuration and offering is slightly different, YARN does not contain the Job Tracker UI.

Is there any way to capture memory and CPU? Is there a log that is maintained that can be leveraged to extract the information out?

The cluster type and HDInsight version is **Spark on Linux (HDI 3.4.1000.0)**

Answer (score 0):

You could use Spark History Server. Here's an article about it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-apache-spark-job-debugging

HDI clusters v3.4 have Spark 1.6.2, so the REST API is at: http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/monitoring.html#rest-api